# Iterate object arraylist with if condition

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a newbie of Java. I have a problem with object ArrayList that cannot iterate until the end when it doesn't catch up with If condition. In this code, if I input the second movie name and check for 'If condition', this condition doesn't iterate till the end. Seems like 'If condition' works for the first object value of ArrayList. Please someone points out to me what's wrong with this. Thanks in advances!

Here is the code:

```
    boolean isFound=false;
    for (Movies item: movie_list) {
        if(item!=null && item.getMovie_name().contains(movie_name)) {
            System.out.println("Movie exist");
            isFound=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isFound) {
        System.out.println("Movie doesn't exist!");
    }
 }
```

Comment: where and what is the "movie_name" ?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, after the first iteration the loop finished right? That's cause of the break; you've set when the condition is true.

Comment: Why don't you print the movie name each time through the loop. That way you can answer this yourself.

Comment: @MarkusG. yes. when the condition is true, the loop will be break. If the condition is not true, it needs to iterate the whole list until the condition meets. But it doesn't work even for user input, 'movie_name' , that is still in movie_list.

Comment: @Joe "movie_name" is the user input.

Comment: @NomadMaker yep, I'd already tried out and tested by printing out of each item. It's working but when it doesn't meet the "If condition", "item" needs loop the whole list, doesn't it??  but it doesn't work correctly....

Comment: if the user input "movie_name" contains the invisible NEWLINE (\n) or CARIAGE RETURN (\r) then you never achieve a TRUE

Comment: @Joe sry for late return! Yep I found it finally!! Thank you!